# Pandas dataframe to Redshift psql table

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to keep inserting data into Redshift table. This method often worked for me:

```
test_df.to_sql('MY_table', engine, index=False, if_exists ='append')
```

As you can see, I have already used 'append' for new insertion. But today redshift kept giving me error saying:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) Relation "MY_table" already exists

Do you know why?

Comment: Does it work if the table name is in all lower case?