# Pandas df.to_sql not working for redshift

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
igers = create_engine('postgres://%s:%s@%s/ibdrs' %(igersUser, igersPwd, igersHost), encoding="utf-8")
df.to_sql('Table_Named_Something', igers, if_exists='replace', schema='Schema', index = False)
```

Using the above code I am getting an error `(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) Relation "Table_Named_Something" already exists`

I thought that the if_exists='replace' should drop and recreate the table; am I wrong?  why would that not work on redshift?

Comment: No I don't have a table named table.  It has another name, but the data is sensitive and I have to sanitize it to make sure that there is 0 chance someone happens upon it.

Comment: Once again, that is not the table name.  Let me change the code so you can get unstuck there.  I have already verified the permissions.

Comment: I didn't realize I didn't copy the igers variable part sorry about that.  Igers is the variable create_engine is assigned to.  Beyond that you cannot have the rest since it is login and database address data

Comment: Are you very sure you are using *replace* and NOT *append*? Check code carefully. Similar Redshift/Pandas posts show issue emerges with *append*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54240688/1422451 (weeks ago); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312684/pandas-dataframe-to-redshift-psql-table (months ago). But no issue with *replace* (lots of upvotes): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709820/1422451 (years ago).

Comment: Yes I am very sure it says replace.  Good to know about the append though.

Comment: See last link as I just edited comment with no issue with *replace*. It must be your user privileges as you may not have ownership privileges. Try running an engine query: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_schema.my_table` and check any error. And if no error run it before the `to_sql` call.

Comment: the drop command works without issue.  The user I am using is a superuser, so it shouldn't even need specific permissions; I did give it them though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will sound weird, but I faced the same issue and it was solved when I changed the table name to lowercase.

Comment: solved the issue for me lol....silly